# a misunderstanding about the definition of f(x)

Tags: functions

well I have a little misunderstanding here

if the functions is just a mapping tool then would not it make more sense to say that it can not take any value

so to make my question a little clearer

what I want to say is a function is just a tool a mapping tool that maps certain inputs to certain outputs and therefore the function it self does not occupy any value in this procedur

but very clearly where ever I look always people define f(x) as the value of the function at x

well I see that this is very contradictory

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you're asking here. If English is not your first language, you can write in whatever language you speak in, and someone will try to translate it.

Comment: Indeed $f$ and $f(x)$ are different things, (most of the time) $f(x)$ is not even a function.


When people say that $f(x)=e^x+\sin(x)$, for all $x\in \mathbb R$, this, by itself, is not the definition of a function, but it determines a certain function **uniquely**, i.e., there exists only one function $g\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto g(x)$ such that $\forall x\in\mathbb R\left(g(x)=f(x)\right)$. In this example clearly $g\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto e^x+\sin (x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, a function $f: S \to T$ is a rule that for each element $s \in S$ gives you an element $f(s)\in T$. As an example we write $f(x)= x^2$, because its a convenient way to say that $f$ is the rule that takes something and squares it.

Alternatively, you can think of a function $f: S \to T$ as a subset  $F \subset S \times T$ where for each $s \in S$, there exists a unique $t \in T$ so that $(s,t) \in F$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f$ whose output is double its input.  We can write $f: x\to 2x$, but we can also write this a different way as $f(x)=2x$.  We are defining $f$ via explaining what it does to every input.  This is enough, because that specifies the function uniquely.